# Hide stream URL

Tags: wordpress, audio, stream

I currently run an online radio station and have a play button that links to my stream. When you click this on mobile it comes up with the streams URL, is there anyway of hiding this?

Thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you want to hide it on mobile platform?

Comment: For example, if you go to my website www.subtle.fm and click the play button on mobile, on iPhones you can see the stream URL, I wish to hide this and maybe show the words, Subtle FM Now Live. I've attached a screenshot - https://screencast.com/t/sA7YWipswf